# How to customise the callout view in map view

Tags: ios

How to show the customise callouts in the map view? If we tap the pin its show like in this in image

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. First step should always be searching. Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift mkmapkit callout` ... you'll find numerous examples of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using GoogleMaps SDK:
Depends upon the use case that you're trying to achieve.
If only a single marker can be selected, then you can use the marker markerInfoWindow to show a custom view on the selected marker.

Otherwise, If multiple markers could be shown as depicted in the image, then use GMSMarker iconView property and use different views for different states .
Hope this helps!!

Comment: we using mapkit. To show the callout view in map view